# last-child is not working in IE8 browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

CSS : last-child is not working in IE8 browser any alternate solution for this tag.

I tried with :last-of-type, but also it is not working.

Can any one help me on this ?

Thanks
Jagadeesh.N

Comment: maybe you could using jQuery

Answer (score 1):

`:first-child` is only supported in IE8 but sorry to say that `:last-child` isn't supported for IE8.

To be easy just define the class name for that div and apply the css

---

Solution with jQuery:

```
$('*').last().addClass('last-child');
```

Or,

```
$('*:last-child').addClass('last-child');/*use it with care*/
```

So now you can simply use `div.last-child` as a selector in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not support `:last-child` So, you can use this method:

> Your best bet is to explicitly add a last-child (or similar) class to
>   that item, and apply li.last-child instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can always load a polyfill for that:

```
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Here's the link: http://selectivizr.com/